# LinkedIn V2 API permission's don't seem to be working

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

I'm developing an app which integrates some linked-in functionality, and we are testing out the version 2 API.

But when we try and request anything from the API we retrieve an error which states the following:

```
{"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access /me GET ","status":403}
```

The call we are making is this:
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

**I'm attaching our OAuth2 code like this, after retrieving it from the appropriate URL:**

```
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + authCode);
```

**Here is the complete request we make to the linkedin API:**

```
// start rest client
var client = new RestClient("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/");

// retrieve our linkedin profile
var request = new RestRequest("me", Method.GET);

// attach our auth code
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + authCode);

// execute query
var response = client.Execute(request); 

// display the result on the screen
ViewBag.Message = "output: " + response.Content;
```

On linked-in we're using OAuth2 to authenticate our user token, and requesting all the permissions using:

```
&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20rw_company_admin%20w_share
```

Relevant documentation link:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2

Additionally, I've tested our OAuth2 token with the version 1 API, and it functions perfectly fine for everything we throw at it.

I've done lots of digging into this, and there is some mention of three legged authorisation but no supporting linked-in article which I can find, which describes this process.

My question is, does anyone know how to make this work properly, has anyone had success with the V2 API, and can you help me solve my issue with the request.

Comment: I'm struggling with this as well. I've found some evidence that non-LI devs have success with the V2 API, but the amount of issues I see suggests that there's something very basic that we're missing. My guess is that we need some kind of additional approval from LI to use the V2 API. Please let me know if you find any kind of success!

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I believe the three-legged auth process is the same for both V1 and V2. From what I can see, my auth token from V1 is technically "working" with V2, it just doesn't have adequate permission to do... anything.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on this, we're struggling with it too and would really like official feedback from LI as it is confusing they can't tell us 'to use our V2 API you must be a partner' is nowhere.

Comment: I'm also struggeling with this. Did anyone find a solution for his? Do we really need to ask LI about having access to v2 api? If so, where can we do this? WE're already a partner in the dev program.

Comment: You need access to the V2 API and you must be a linked in partner and make sure you have your app settings with the correct fields in the developer settings on their site. We never got V2 access in the end.

Comment: Though it's not clear from the documentation, LinkedIn API is private. You need to request authorisation from them: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Answer (score 1):

You need to change permissions. Some of them has deprecated(r_basicprofile).
I recommend use  Migration FAQ. Please see next link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/migration-faq